# How to do OAuth2 Authorization in ASP.NET Core for Swagger UI using Swashbuckle

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger, swashbuckle

Swashbuckle OAuth2 Authorization with Client Credentials Flow in `DotNet Core 2`

I want to set Implicit `Flow`, `AuthorizationUrl`, different `Scopes`, default selected `Client-id`,
so, after clicking authorize, it should navigate to different tab, opening `AuthorizationUrl` and make user logged in `Swagger`. So, next time user can see `log out` option.

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info()
    {
        Title = "",
        Description = "All rights reserved."
    });


    c.AddSecurityDefinition("oauth2", new OAuth2Scheme
    {
        Flow = "implicit",
        AuthorizationUrl = "https://...",
        Scopes = new Dictionary<string, string> {
            { "", "Read/Write" }
        }

    });
});
```

and `Configure()` having,

```
app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI(c => {
    c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "iModelAcquisitionService");
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try below steps to enable implict Oauth2 flow :

1. Change the Startup.cs and replace in the ConfigureServices method the previous added with this:

   ```
   services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
   {
       c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info { Title = "My API", Version = "v1" });
       c.AddSecurityDefinition("oauth2", new OAuth2Scheme
       {
           Type = "oauth2",
           Flow = "implicit",
           AuthorizationUrl = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/cb1c3f2e-a2dd-4fde-bf8f-f75ab18b21ac/oauth2/authorize",
           Scopes = new Dictionary<string, string>
           {
                   { "accessApi", "Access read operations" },

           },
           TokenUrl = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/cb1c3f2e-a2dd-4fde-bf8f-f75ab18b21ac/oauth2/token"
       });
   });
   ```
2. And replace the following in the Configure method:

   ```
   app.UseSwagger();
   app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
   {
       c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My API V1");
       c.OAuthClientId("19c73866-562f-482a-bafb-89d9fe9b0aaa");
       c.OAuthAppName("Swagger Api Calls");


   });
   ```
3. Go to the swagger endpoint: http://localhost:xxx/swagger and click `Authorize` button .

Comment: What should be the `ClientId`, swagger dont allow use of existing `appSettings.json`'s clientId, they are different

Comment: client id is the application id you registered in your identity provider(Oauth server)